# Anime with a woman saving a child from being hit by a car by shielding them with her body... only to accidentally squeeze too hard

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember someone posting this on the r/mutantsandmasterminds SubReddit a few years ago, with the clip involving a young woman (I don't recall the hair color exactly, but I think it was brown, or possibly black) who sees a child about to be run down by a car. So she runs in and grabs them, shielding them with her body, with the car smashing into her, and breaking around her due to her being superhumanly strong/tough...

Except then the child she was trying to save has blood fountaining out of them because she failed to control her super-strength, and squeezed them too hard.

I think I looked up the anime at the time, but the name has left my mind.

Comment: Harry Harrison got there first...

Comment: @DavidW which harrison story?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Yozakura Quartet: Hana no Uta](https://myanimelist.net/anime/18497/Yozakura_Quartet:_Hana_no_Uta)*.

> Hundreds of years ago, the borders between the worlds of humans and
> youkai temporarily overlapped, resulting in many residents of both
> crossing over to the other side. In the years since this event, the
> city of Sakurashin has become a central hub for all inter-dimensional
> affairs—a result of both the sacred Seven Pillars around the city
> serving as a beacon for the youkai, and the efforts of the Hiizumi
> Life Counseling Office in keeping the townsfolk happy. This office is
> composed of Hime Yarizakura, the young mayor of the city; satori Ao
> Nanami, who can read people's minds; half-youkai Kotoha Isone, who can
> summon anything by speaking a word; oni siblings, Kyousuke and Touka
> Kishi; and the office director Akina Hiizumi, who inherited his
> family's ability to force youkai back to their world.

You can see the clip [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/obglka/the_tragic_consequences_of_poorly_thought_out/)
**NSFW Warning: Gory**

> [image]